# Predictive text inside the terminal in Dart

Tags: command-line, dart, output, predict

Trying to create a command line tool for use in a web framework and want to have predictive text inside the terminal to save typing. So far I've been using:

```
stdout.writeln('Text to output'); // To output to terminal
stdin.readLineSync(); // For reading responses from the terminal
```

However, using the writeln function doesn't output to the user input area in the terminal, but rather a system response. What I need is to output to the user input in the terminal, like how the Symfony framework operates in PHP, so that when typing a guess can be given and the user can tab to complete (again, see the symfony CRUD or doctrine entity generator for an idea of the desired functionality).

I do see that using readLineSync might also be a problem (as the script will need to listen for user input and not be blocked).

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I guess if you want tab completion etc. you have to code it yourself. This is not included in dart.